# PayPal Classic APIs determine account type

Tags: python, paypal

How do I determine which type of account a person has when using the permissions api? I need to make a different decision if they have a pro account versus a standard business account. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be be done using the [Adaptive Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-accounts/) API and more specifically the [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) call.

A successful response will include the `UserInfoType` Fields including the `accountType` which is what you're looking for.

You can find what a successful response looks like [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptiveAccounts), click on `GetVerifiedStatus` and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to see that via the API.  That's typically something you'd leave up to the end-user to know when they're signing up.  Ask them if they have Pro or not, and based on that, setup your permissions request accordingly.

Comment: This could be very useful given most customers seem to know they "have PayPal" but that really can mean a lot of different things, from direct payments to pay now buttons, but thanks for the reply!